# Question about proving Lebesgue-Vitali theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

The theorem gives the equivalent criterion when a bounded rel-value function is Riemann integrable, I can follow much of the proof but some details. I will mark it in bold.

Proof. Suppose that $f$ is Riemann integrable. Then for each positive integer $n$ we can choose a partition $\mathscr{P}_n$ of $[a, b]$ such that $u\left(f, \mathscr{P}_n\right)-l\left(f, \mathscr{P}_n\right)<1 / n$. We can assume that for each $n$ the partition $\mathscr{P}_{n+1}$ is a refinement of the partition $\mathscr{P}_n$. Define sequences $\left\{g_n\right\}$ and $\left\{h_n\right\}$ of functions on $[a, b]$ by letting $g_n$ and $h_n$ agree with $f$ at the point $a$ and letting them be constant on each interval of the form $\left(a_{i-1}, a_i\right]$ determined by $\mathscr{P}_n$, there having the values $\inf \left\{f(x): a_{i-1} \leq x \leq a_i\right\}$ and $\sup \left\{f(x): a_{i-1} \leq x \leq a_i\right\}$, respectively.

Then $\left\{g_n\right\}$ is an increasing sequence of simple Borel functions that satisfy $g_n \leq f$ and $\int_{[a, b]} g_n d \lambda=l\left(f, \mathscr{P}_n\right)$ for each $n$, and $\left\{h_n\right\}$ is a decreasing sequence of simple Borel functions that satisfy $h_n \geq f$ and $\int_{[a, b]} h_n d \lambda=u\left(f, \mathscr{P}_n\right)$ for each $n$. Since $f$ is bounded, the sequences $\left\{g_n\right\}$ and $\left\{h_n\right\}$ are bounded. Define functions $g$ and $h$ by $g=\lim _n g_n$ and $h=\lim _n h_n$. Then $g$ and $h$ are Borel measurable, and the dominated convergence theorem implies that $g$ and $h$ are Lebesgue integrable, with $\int_{[a, b]} g d \lambda$ and $\int_{[a, b]} h d \lambda$ equal to $\lim _n l\left(f, \mathscr{P}_n\right)$ and $\lim _n u\left(f, \mathscr{P}_n\right)$, respectively, and so to the Riemann integral of $f$. Thus $\int_{[a, b]}(h-$ g) $d \lambda=0$. Since in addition $h-g \geq 0$, Corollary 2.3.12 implies that
$$
g(x)=h(x) \text { for almost every } x \text { in }[a, b] .
$$

This relation has two consequences. **For the first, note that if $g(x)=h(x)$ and if $x$ is a point in $[a, b]$ that is not a division point in any of the partitions $\mathscr{P}_n$, then $f$ is continuous at $x$.**

My question is

> Why do we need to restrict $x$ so that is not a tagged point? Why under that circumstance, $f$ is continuous at $x$?

It seems $\mathscr{P}_n^{c} \cap [a,b]$ is an open set in the subspace topology and uses the equivalent definition for continuity at a point (The oscillation is zero) that can explain my question, but I am not sure.

Comment: The set of all endpoints $P:=\cup_n\mathcal{P}_n$ is countable and hence of measure zero. $f$ is continuous on the complement of $P\cup\{x\in[a,b]: g(x)<f(x)\}$ which of measure zero as $g=f$ a.s.

Comment: Yes, but why at endpoints, f is not continuous?

Comment: $f$ might be (or not) continuous at the endpoints, but by not even considering, we still get continuity almost everywhere. For example $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous everywhere. If we remove $D=\{0,1\}\cup\{1/2\}\cup\{1/4,3/4\}\cup\ldots$, $f$ is continuous at every point in $[0,1]\setminus D$.